# $a_1<1,$ $a_{m+1}\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}+1-\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}\leq a_m$ and $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}a_m>0?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence of positive numbers $\{a_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ such that $a_1<1,$ $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}a_m>0$ and
$$a_{m+1}\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}+1-\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}\leq a_m, \quad m>1?$$

Without the condition $a_1<1$ we can simply take $a_m=1$ for all $m$. I, however, can't see whether starting with some $a_1<1$ we can still get a non-zero limit as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: The condition can be rewritten 

$$b_1<0 , \ \lim b_n=-1$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}b_{m+1}\leq b_m, \quad m>1$$ It could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition can be rewritten

$$c_n\triangleq1-a_n$$

$$c_1<0 , \ \lim c_n=-1$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}c_{m+1}\geq c_m, \quad m>1$$

So by iteration $c_n$ **is positive.**

$$ \sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}c_{m+1}\geq c_m $$

Using telescopic product (which works by positivity):

$$ c_n\geq \sqrt{\dfrac{\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}(m+1)}{\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}m}}c_1=\sqrt{n}c_1 $$

So this isn't possible to have

$$ \lim a_n=0 $$ equivalent to $$ \lim c_n= 1$$

**Conclusion**

No such sequence exists.